# Dynamically Size a Div Based on Other Divs

Tags: php, dom

Using PHP only with no JavaScript, is it possible to position and size a div based on two other divs?

I know how to do it with JavaScript, but want to avoid using JavaScript for this if at all possible.  Essentially, it's the day view of a calendar.  The day is broken up into 15 minute intervals, depicted by divs.  If an appointment lasts 2 hours, starting at 8am, we want to draw a div over the time divs, starting at the 8am div, and extending down to the 10am div.

I'm really thinking there is no way to do this without JavaScript, but JavaScript is Satan's meanest invention, and I'd like to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Misread "Satan" as "Safari", hah.

Comment: JavaScript is Satans invention? I guess I like Satan then..

Comment: Can you expand on that?  Is there a way to have CSS use multipliers to get the height to be the correct height?  Or would I need a different class for each time span?  1 hour, 2 hours, 15 minutes, etc?

Comment: Duh!  I just need to use the style attribute and the multiplier in the php.  Thanks atlavis.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid javascript is really difficult today :) you preclude some really cool features and XHR functionality. However, you can easily create inline code and work with CSS. Something like

```
<div style=" <?php echo (yourstyleyear);"?>></div>
```

Comment: ops... i'm sorry i read comments after my answer. Feel free to accept atlavis :)

Comment: You posted answer, not me ;-)